# Show notification when admin have a new message from user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

In my ASP.net MVC4 project users can send messages to admin. Admin can check that messages in any time in a special section of his page without any problem. I am little bit confused with next thing: For my thinking it will be better to make a notification in webpage of admin which will mean that he have a new messages from users instead of сhecking that section everytime. What the best way to realise it (**to show a notification**)?!

Answer (score 1):

I would implement Signal-R for that purpose. When the server finds a new message waiting for the admin, it would send a notification to your app, and you then just need to show a toast with a link to your existing page for instance...

You can find more info about this technology here: http://www.asp.net/signalr

Example of toast library: https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/

Comment: Hello @FredM Thanks for your answer. I heard about SignalR before but mostly people use it to make chat application. As I understand we have Real Time concept. Can you say me in details how server can find new messages?! Right know in my application all information which user submit after filling out forms just stored in database and admin downloads that information from database. As I understand now I need to send something like signal to server, right?! Do you have any example how to realise it?!

Comment: If the app that fills the DB with the form content is the same as the one that needs to display the messages to the admin, you could simply trigger the notification after the form is successfully submitted and stored. Otherwise, your admin app could check for new messages every once in a while (polling) or subscribe to a SQL event to be notified as soon as a new message comes in.

Comment: First variant which you described that's what I am trying right now but unfortunately still have problems with realization. Can you advise may be commands which I need to use to send that notification to admin page when user submit information from forms in his page.

Comment: If you check the sample at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr, you can see the 2 parts needed: a jQuery script that waits for signals from the server, this is where you would use the toast to display the notification. That part would only be present on a page that is only accessible to the admin. The other part is the server side code that sends the signal. That method should be place just after you stored the submitted message in your DB...